# Regular Expression to split a string with parentheses

Tags: c#, regex

Need help with RegEx. Using C#.

Group of Words in parentheses (round or box or curly) should be considered as one word. The part, which is outside parentheses, should split based on white space ' '.

A) Test Case –

Input - `Andrew. (The Great Musician) John Smith-Lt.Gen3rd`

Result (Array of string) –
1. Andrew.
2. The Great Musician
3. John
4. Smith-Lt.Gen3rd

B) Test Case –

Input - `Andrew. John`

Result (Array of string) –
1. Andrew.
2. John

C) Test Case –

Input - `Andrew {The Great} Pirate`

Result (Array of string) –
 1. Andrew
 2. The Great
 3. Pirate

The input is name of a person or any other entity. Current system is very old written in Access. They did it by scanning character by character. I am replacing it with C#.

I thought of doing it in two steps – first parentheses based split and then word split.

I wanted to throw these cases out as bad input -

1. Only Starting or ending parentheses available
2. nested parentheses

Overall, I wanted to split only well-formed (if start parentheses is there, there must be an ending) Inputs only.

Comment: Since parentheses can be nested, regexes are the wrong tool for the job. You'll have to write a parser.

Comment: That's not entirely true.  Based on the input, if you know that braces of the same type won't be nested, you're fine.

Comment: `"And {what (about strings} like) this?"`

Comment: @JackManey I bet it's safe to assume these won't occur

Comment: @JanDvorak ...based upon what, exactly?

Comment: @JackManey based on the sample input, and based on the semantics I infer on the parentheses

Answer (score 5):

Here is a regex that will give the proper results from your examples:

```
\s(?=.*?(?:\(|\{|\[).*?(?:\]|\}|\)).*?)|(?<=(?:\(|\[|\{).*?(?:\}|\]|\)).*?)\s
```

This regex is in two parts, separated by an `|`(OR) statement:

1. `\s(?=.*?(?:\(|\{|\[).*?(?:\]|\}|\)).*?)`    -  Looks for a white space before sets of `()`, `[]`, or `{}`
2. `(?<=(?:\(|\[|\{).*?(?:\}|\]|\)).*?)\s` - Looks for a white space after sets of `()`, `[]`, or `{}`

Here is the breakdown of each part:

Part 1 (`\s(?=.*?(?:\(|\{|\[).*?(?:\]|\}|\)).*?)`):

```
1. \s             - matches white space
2. (?=            - Begins a lookahead assertion (What is included must exist after the \s
3. .*?            - Looks for any character any number of times. The `?` makes in ungreedy, so it will grab the least number it needs
4. (?:\(|\{|\[)   - A non passive group looking for `(`, `{`, or `[`
5. .*?            - Same as #3
6. (?:\]|\}|\))   - The reverse of #4
7. .*?            - Same as #3
8. )              - Closes the lookahead.  #3 through #7 are in the lookahead.
```

Part 2 is the same thing, but instead of the lookahead (`(?=)`) it has a lookbehind (`(?<=)`)

After Questions edit by author:

For a regex that will search for lines with only complete parentheses, you can use this:

`.*\(.*(?=.*?\).*?)|(?<=.*?\(.*?).*\).*`

You can use it to replace `(` and `)` with `{` and `}` or `[` and `]` so you have complete curly and square brackets.

Answer (score 1):

How about this:

```
Regex regexObj = new Regex(
    @"(?<=\()       # Assert that the previous character is a (
    [^(){}[\]]+     # Match one or more non-paren/brace/bracket characters
    (?=\))          # Assert that the next character is a )
    |               # or
    (?<=\{)[^(){}[\]]+(?=\}) # Match {...}
    |               # or 
    (?<=\[)[^(){}[\]]+(?=\]) # Match [...]
    |               # or
    [^(){}[\]\s]+   # Match anything except whitespace or parens/braces/brackets", 
    RegexOptions.IgnorePatternWhitespace);
```

This assumes no nested parentheses/braces/brackets.